Text in SVGs appears round/smooth when added to the resource system
Qt version: 5.15.15
I'm trying to create some very simple SVG files using https://editsvg.online/editor.html, and then import them in my Qt Project for use.
I'm creating 6 very simple SVGs, just symbols for "+X", "+Y", "+Z", "-X", "-Y", and "-Z".
In the editor, and when the final product is viewed in a browser, it looks fine! But once imported into the QRC, it is smoothed/rounded and loses a lot of detail.
This shows up both when looking at the QRC file:

And when viewing it in the final program:

Is there some way to configure/tell Qt to use a higher resolution when working with SVGs?
Here is an example SVG, for "-Z":
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="24.000000000000004" height="24.000000000000004" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->
 <title>minus_z</title>
 <g class="layer">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <text fill="#000000" font-family="Serif" font-size="24" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" style="cursor: move;" text-anchor="middle" transform="matrix(0.840809, 0, 0, 0.894209, 10.2146, 12.059)" x="2.16" xml:space="preserve" y="8.04">-Z</text>
 </g>
</svg>

And here's what it looks like in a browser:


This question is similar to: SVG exported from Inkscape are rendered with different font. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You seem to have two different problems here. First of all, the font family doesn't seem to be recognized: you specified the generic "Serif", but the icons show a "sans serif" font (see the difference); in theory, Qt should use its font matching algorithm and get the closest match based on installed fonts: try checking your font list and change the value of the font-family attribute accordingly, using a recognizable font, then see if something changes. Then, the blurred result is caused by the small icon size and the stroke set for the font outline.

Since QIcon returns a pixmap (or renders the icon) based on a given size, and by default icons are relatively small, the painter automatically draws the font outline with a standard QPen that is based on the paint device (based on the stroke values, it probably is a 1-pixel pen). If, for instance, you have a default icon size of 16x16, a 1 pixel pen is a lot for a font outline. Just remove all stroke related attributes in the <text> definition and you should at least get a better result about this "blurring" issue. The font family aspect remains, though.

If you also notice blurriness, check the other questions about that. If you find no solution on Stack Overflow, ask a new question that contains a [mre]. Keep this one as a sign post, it's a good for that, imo.

@musicamante Sorry all, I was out sick for a few days. I tried adding FreeSerif.ttf to the resources file, then changing the font-family to be "FreeSerif". This did not change it to a serif font, unfortunately. I also did remove all "stroke" based entries, which seems to have made it a bit better.

@TylerShellberg Note that adding a font to the resource files is not sufficient, you must also add it using QFontDatabase. It may be possible that the QtSvg implementation is able to load the font from the resources using the appropriate path (as qrc://) in the svg declaration, but I'm not completely sure. Adding the font to the database seems to be more reliable anyway. Also ensure that the font family is correct, the file name is irrelevant.

@musicamante What do you mean about the font family being correct? What are the families? What should it be set to? From looking online I thought it was just a list of fonts in order of priority.

@TylerShellberg Fonts are normally "installed" and eventually chosen based on their family, which usually is an arbitrary string. The font matching algorithm eventually chooses the font based on a given family, checking all available fonts that may correspond to that match, and eventually return one (or many, based on an arbitrary priority). The point is, you cannot base a font selection on the file name of that font, as it may be completely inconsistent with its contents: simply put, the file name is basically irrelevant as it »

@musicamante Ah, ok. So use the return from addApplicationFont() and then applicationFontFamilies() to determine what the family actually is, then edit the SVG XMLs to set that as the family?

@TylerShellberg » would be naming an image file as "2.png" even though it's a jpg image that shows a picture of the number 1. The file name is irrelevant, you must check the font family (or families) and select it based on that - hoping that the font matching algorithm respect it accordingly, and no other similar font with similar families already exists and was given a higher priority for some reasons.

@TylerShellberg That's probably the most (but not absolutely) reliable option. Using the whole result of applicationFontFamilies(id) may increase the possibility of proper matching, but that's never an absolute certainty. In reality, the only reliable options, as long as you want 100% consistent icons, are to either create the SVG files based on the pure vector data you get on your system for a given font (without using any <text> entry), or provide a font with very specific family name(s).

@musicamante Thanks for the help! I got it working now with the call to addApplicationFont() and then modifying the SVGs with the return from applicationFontFamilies(). If you'd like to put it in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

@TylerShellberg I think it would be better if you added your own answer, since you've found a proper way to implement it. OTOH, consider if you really need to add a custom font just to display small letters as icons. Unless those letters are actually dynamically created (meaning that, possibly, any character could be displayed), it would probably be better to create those SVG icons (using paths, instead of text) and include them in the resources. You could even create a small script that generates those SVG files (through QSvgGenerator and using QPainterPath) whenever you need new ones.

As the comments say, the real issue was that this was really text and not an SVG - therefore to get it to look the same we'd need to make sure the preferred font is loaded into QT.
Here's the sum of changes I made:
1: Remove all 'stroke' entries from the SVGs
2: Add a new preferred font to the source directory, I chose "FreeSerif" but any will do. I also added it to the QRC file but I'm not positive if that's needed or not.
3: Call int QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(const QString &fileName) on the path to the new font.
4: If you put in the path correctly, the return will be something other than -1. (I personally had to do a post-build step to copy the font over to the build folder, but this may not apply to everyone)
5: Temporarily, add a line where you pass that ID to QStringList QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(int id). This will give the font family of the newly added font. Once you write it down somewhere, you can delete this line.
6: Open the SVGs and edit the 'font-family' tag to match the return from applicationFontFamilies().
7: Done!

If you add the font to the resources and properly include them in the project/build, you don't need to copy anything else after that, just access the font using the standard qrc:// resources syntax.
